# Simplify assuming $x$ is small

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I would like to assume that $x$ is small so that values of the order $x^2$ (and higher orders) are negligible.

For example, I would like *Mathematica* to return $1-2m$ when I ask it  to simplify $(1-x)^2$. Something like

```
Assuming[{x->0},Simplify[(1-x)^2]]
```

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html#26978

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conditional replacement rule to set any power of `x` higher than 1 to zero:

```
simp[expr_, x_] := ExpandAll[expr] /. {Power[x, a_] /; a > 1 -> 0}

simp[(1/x - 3 x + 4 - x)^4, x]
simp[(1 - x)^2, x]
(* -416 + 1/x^4 + 16/x^3 + 80/x^2 + 64/x - 256 x *)
(* 1 - 2 x *)
```

Of course, the easy way to do it would be to just take the `Series` and convert the answer to `Normal` form,

```
Series[(1/x - 3 x + 4 - x)^4, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal
(* -416 + 1/x^4 + 16/x^3 + 80/x^2 + 64/x - 256 x *)
```